# Compress JSON sent from Ionic2 app to Java REST Server

Tags: java, json, angular, ionic2, gzip

Is there any way to compress JSON prior to submitting it to the server? I've tried using Pako to GZIP the JSON but for some reason the server code keeps telling me that it's not a GZIP String

I don't really care what type of compression it is as long as it could be compressed on Ionic2 client side and decompressed(inflated) in java

Here is what I have tried:

```
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let gzippedBody = Pako.gzip(body);
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Encoding" : "gzip"});
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(url, gzippedBody, options);
```

On the server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ValidatorResult saveCancelledSessionNotes(@RequestBody String json ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    json = decompress(json.getBytes());
}
 public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(gis);
        return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

Stacktrace on the server:

`java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)`

Comment: Maybe the `Content-Type`  should be `application/gzip` since what you're sending is gzip?

Comment: I tried that, same results. It seems like Pako.gzip is not putting it in the right format but I don't know how to fix it.